# object graph for better testability

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit

**Should I refactor my system under test code to be accepting an object graph instead of each individual dependency?**

Because I did not start my solution having unit testing in mind, I am refactoring for testability.

I'm injecting all of my dependencies through the constructor:

```
var myApp = new MyClass(DependencyOne, DependencyTwo, ...DependencyTen)
```

Within the constructor I am initializing my privates to those dependencies:

```
MyClass
{
  MyClass(IDependencyOne, IDependencyTwo, ...IDependencyTen)
  {
    dependencyOne = IDependencyOne;
    dependencyTwo = dependencyTwo ;
    ...
    dependencyTen = IDependencyTen;

  }
}
```

For my unit testing, I can now Mock each dependency:

```
var mockDep1 = new Mock<IDependencyOne>();
var mockDep2 = new Mock<IDependencyTwo>();
...
var sut = new MyClass(mockDep1.Object, mockDep2.Object..)
```

**What is the best-standards way of structuring code that accepts a lot of dependencies to be testable?**

Comment: Are you using IoC? Otherwise you can use a testable pattern - http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/06/the-testable-object-pattern.html

Comment: thanks for the link. i like that a lot; however, what do you do if you need to mock one of the dependencies? it breaks the pattern

Comment: Also, take a look at the AutoMocking systems like this http://docs.structuremap.net/AutoMocker.htm

Comment: What do you mean by to mock one of the dependencies?

Comment: regarding your first link, the typepad, it talks about this pattern of creating an instance of all of the dependencies using a static method ... what if you want to pass a mock of a dependency instead ? another words, you dont want the concrete class StubEditorView as a dependency, you want Mock<StubEditorView>() of it

Comment: It's just a method, that returns you an instance of your class, with already mocked dependencies. So you are able to change one property to another value.

Comment: the moq+structuremap looks cool i will check it out thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108428/discussion-between-valentin-and-l).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I consider, there are several ways to resolve dependencies in tests.

I suggest to use [automocking containers](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/) for example [structure map](http://docs.structuremap.net/AutoMocker.htm) 
It's very clean and it's easy to add dependencies without having to update test classes.

Also, you can avoid using IoC and resolve all dependencies manually or use [testable pattern](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/06/the-testable-object-pattern.html).

Comment: what if you want to mock the View or Service? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByqKtGmtuLzZVkppajI1U004aWM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Sorry,  I don't have an access to this site. If you want to share, put it in the question.